# How to add dynamic color in angular html page

Tags: angular, ionic3

If I try to add this within div tag.  `<div>{{list.color_code}}</div>`

then its perfect work but when i try this inline css, then it not reflect on inspect element of browser. style tag remain empty in inspect element `style = "";`

I am using below syntax.

```
<div style="background:{{list.color_code}}">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
<div [style.background]="list.color_code">Hello</div>
```

Comment: @abhishek if it helped you, consider upvoting the answer and selecting it as resolved !

Comment: You are welcome @abhishek Please accept this answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

For changing style dynamically, use ngClass to switch classes. Evaluate some condition that can change with a click event or some other way.

```
<button type="button" (click)="switchClass()" class="class1" [ngClass]="switch ? 'class1' : 'class2'">Some element</button>
```